# Probleme about rebooting the Raspberry PI after update and upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi2

As you can read in the title of the post, I have a problem about rebooting the Raspberry PI after doing :

```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
```

When the updating and upgrading finished, I restart the Raspberry and I just have a black monitor and the POWER LED (Red) is ON and the Green Led is also ON. 
This is the second time the problem appear on my Raspberry PI.

Today, I downloaded the Raspbian and did all the manipulation to boot the Raspberry. And now the problem re-appear. The First time that the problem appear, I just formated the SD Card and I wrote the Raspbian in the SD Card.

If some one had the same problem, please help me to solve it.

Thank you in advance.

PS : I am using a Raspberry PI model B+.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem like You.
For me, I have 2 possible reasons :

1) Power Supply - I recommended 5V 2A Power Supply
2) Network ethernet patch cable unshielded (without shield or ground line)

This problems with cable I had also on R-Pi2. Buying shielded cable solve my problems with R-Pi hangs on boot after reboot.

Now my cable looks like this one : 
http://www.cabling-supplies.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/512x512/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/a/cat6a-shielded_1.jpg

Comment: My R-Pi2B has encountered the same problem.The 2 Leds still ON,when power on.I used iPad2 power supply,and  shield ethernet cable with well grounding ,the problem still not resolved.Are there any other reasons? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the two led's status means? Green One Still on stand for what error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the SD card. When the green LED isn't blinking, it means the Pi can't read the SD card. To fix this, get a new SD card.